# Global CSS for all HTML in Play project

Tags: html, css, playframework-2.0

I have a Play! web application with multiple scala.html views. When I want to include CSS for each specific page, I put `{link rel="stylesheet" ... ("stylesheets/something.css")">.` However, I would like to create one default CSS that will contain values that are the same on each html.

My question is, is it possible to create default global CSS (i.e. main.css) which will every HTML use by default unless it has some other CSS defined? Or do I have to include that main.css in every other scala.html (in this case how is it decided which CSS tag takes precedence if two different CSS have the same tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include your mani.css file dynamically. 
You should have one head file (php) and include it in top of every document. If you change head (included css file), the change will affect every page.